# Slider Transition clipping

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I have a strange issue using jquery cycle. But I also think it might be css related. What happens is on transition to the next slide the incoming slide stops about a quarter of the way, then snaps to the end of the screen completing the scrollHorz transition that cycle2 uses. To get rid of the issue I have to set my screen with pretty wide to stop it from happening. I should also include that the slides are scaled to the browser and it only happens in one direction when the slides are moving right to left.

[image: illustration of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Had to scale the size of the containers to browser size